# Error from an Array variable

Tags: java, linux, arrays, compilation

As a result of compilation of the program gave out an error

```
/partrain/src/ParallelTraining.java:309: error: cannot find symbol
                            Array array = contonewdatabase.createArrayOf("string", residualgroupparam);
                            ^
  symbol:   class Array
  location: class Reduce
```

I suspect that didn't connect necessary library. Prompt that it is necessary to connect.

Comment: There is no such thing called `Array` class in-built into Java, if it is a custom type have you added necessary imports?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're looking for the `createArrayOf` method from the `Connection` class in the `java.sql`.  In that case, you forgot the import:

```
import java.sql.Array
```